# heroku.yml not respecting docker build target

Tags: heroku, docker-multi-stage-build

Either I'm doing something wrong or Heroku is messing up. Heroku supports [targeting a particular stage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#targeting-a-stage-from-a-multi-stage-build) in a `Dockerfile`. I have a multistage Dockerfile but Heroku is not respecting the `build.docker.release.target` in my `heroku.yml`. For what it's worth, targeting works fine with `docker-compose.yml`.

I'm trying to keep dev and prod in the same `Dockerfile`. Essentially `dev` and `prod` are forked from `base`. I could flesh it out more, but the stages are:

```
FROM python:3.10.0-slim-buster AS venv

...


FROM python:3.10.0-slim-buster as base

...


FROM base AS dev

...

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.dev.sh"]



FROM base AS prod

...

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

My `heroku.yml` specifically targets the `prod` stage:

```
setup:
    addons:
        - plan: heroku-postgresql
          as: DATABASE
build:
    docker:
        release:
            dockerfile: image/app/Dockerfile
            target: prod
        web: image/app/Dockerfile
    config:
        DJANGO_ENV: production
release:
    image: web
    command:
        - ./deployment-tasks.sh
run:
    web: gunicorn server.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT --log-level debug --access-logfile - --error-logfile -
```

However, Heroku builds all the stages, seems like it just runs down the Dockerfile till the end. The Heroku build logs show that first dev follows base

[image: dev follows base]

and then prod follows dev

[image: prod follows dev]

I would expect it to jump from `base` to `prod`, skipping `dev`.

Is this an issue on my side or Heroku's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this with `heroku.yml` because I've moved to GitHub Actions but I believe the error was having `prod` come after `dev`. Apparently the `--target` flag in `docker build` means it will stop at that stage, so it will run everything before it.